# Using gas, how can I get the offset to a particular label?

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

I'm using `pwnlib` to write a small shellcode for a challenge. My shellcode needs to modify itself to pass application filters. I first wrote it with nasm, and did something like that:

```
        sub        edx, edx
        mov        dl, 0x82
        add        al, do_mov_rdi_rax
        sub        dword [rax], edx
        mov        dh, 0x82
        add        al, do_syscall - do_mov_rdi_rax
        sub        dword [rax], edx
        shr        edi, 31

    do_mov_rdi_rax:
        ; mov    rsi, rax
        ; (with 0x82 added to first byte to pass validation)
        db         0xca, 0x89, 0xc6
        sub        eax, eax

    do_syscall:
        ; syscall
        ; (with 0x82 added to both bytes to pass validation)
        db         0x91, 0x87
```

Pwnlib uses `gas`, however, so my assembly code has to conform to its syntax. Besides the obvious (`//` instead of `;`, `.byte` instead of `db`), I'm stuck with one last problem: while `nasm` happily converted my labels to integers (for `add al, do_mov_rdi_rax` and `add al, do_syscall - do_mov_rdi_rax`), `gas` keeps telling me that it can't represent addressing type `BFD_RELOC_8`, or something like that (I somehow ended up with a French version of `gas`, sorry for the lacking error message).

How can I get the address of the labels as integers? My shellcode is based at address 0 (and gas is told with `.org 0x0`).

Comment: My `gas` (v2.22 from debian) assembled the converted version just fine.

Comment: I'm not in front of my computer, but this is on OS X, and I built binutils from source last week, so it should be fairly up-to-date.

Comment: Yeah it may depend on the output format, I assume on OSX it defaults to mach-o, but on linux it's ELF.

Comment: Now that I'm home, for the record, it's gas 2.25.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since labels wouldn't work, I dug through the `gas` documentation and found that it's also possible to create expression symbols, and that one could use `.` to get the location's address. As it turns out, with the Mach-O output format, `gas` will accept this:

```
.set main, .
    sub     edx, edx
    mov     dl, 0x82
    add     al, do_mov_rdi_rax - main
    sub     dword [rax], edx
    mov     dh, 0x82
    add     al, do_syscall - do_mov_rdi_rax
    sub     dword [rax], edx
    shr     edi, 31

.set do_mov_rdi_rax, .
    // mov  rsi, rax
    // (with 0x82 added to first byte to pass validation)
    .byte   0xca, 0x89, 0xc6
    sub     eax, eax

.set do_syscall, .
    // syscall
    // (with 0x82 added to both bytes to pass validation)
    .byte   0x91, 0x87
```

On the first add, simply using `do_mov_rdi_rax` wouldn't work, but using the difference between it and `main` worked perfectly. (Replacing `main` with a literal zero, however, would not do it.)

There are other problems with it, though: support for `sub dword [rax], edx` appears to be lacking. With gas 2.25 on my Mac, it got assembled as `sub dword [rax+4], edx`, which is very wrong. The version of `as` that ships with Xcode refuses to assemble it, citing absolute 32-bit addressing use; gas 2.24.90 for Debian also refused to assemble it because there would be too many memory references, somehow. Because this is all incorrect, I'll stick with a nasm-assembled binary version of the shellcode instead of using pwnlib's `asm` to compile it.

Comment: If you're using Intel syntax with GAS you need to use MASM's syntax, not NASM's syntax. So either `DWORD PTR [rax]` or just `[rax]` because the size is implied by the use of EDX.

Comment: Someone will need to tell me why using `dword` without a `ptr` silently corrupts the output.

Comment: DWORD is equal to 4 in old versions of MASM.

Comment: For what it's worth, though, the version of `gas` that accepts `sub dword [rax], edx` rejects `sub 4 [rax], edx` with "too many memory references".

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is very unusual and it looks like it requires a relocation that the Mach-O object format used by OS X doesn't support. The problem isn't that you're trying to use a label as an integer, it's that you're trying to use a label as an 8-bit integer. That's not very useful in practice, and something a compiler would never do.

If you really want to add only the lower 8 bits of the address of a symbol (or the difference between two symbols) to the lower 8 bits of RAX you're going to use the label as an 32-bit integer first.

For example you could move it into another 32-bit register first:

```
    mov $do_mov_rdi_rax, %ecx
    add %cl, %al
...
    mov $(do_syscall - do_mov_rdi_rax), %ecx
    add %cl, %al
```

If you don't have a free register for this than you load it from memory:

```
    add indirect_do_mov_rdi_rax, %al
...
    add indirect_difference, %al

indirect_do_mov_rdi_rax:
    .long   do_mov_rdi_rax

indirect_difference:
    .long   do_syscall - do_mov_rdi_rax
```

If didn't really want to be using 8-bit arithmetic and want to do the addition using all 64-bits of the address then you use the 64-bit register RAX instead:

```
    add $do_mov_rdi_rax, %rax
...
    add $(do_syscall - do_mov_rdi_rax), %rax
```

Comment: Conditional jumps all only accept a `rel8` argument, so the ability of any x86 assembler to get an address as an 8 bit operand (or at least the differences of two addresses as an 8 bit operand) is absolutely necessary. (I realize that this means nothing for gas, but nasm does it just fine, too.)

Comment: I'm going this route because the target application (which is [ringzer0team.com](http://ringzer0team.com)'s "level 7" shellcode challenge) rejects any input that contains any byte between 0x30 and 0x82, meaning that, notably, any REX.W-prefixed instruction is off-limits. The input also has to be as close as possible to 20 bytes.

Comment: @znel Branches use a different relocation type, an 8-bit relative one. With a relative relocation there's only one symbol involved, the second address is implied. It's the address of the instruction being fixed up. Your code needs an 8-bit absolute relocation and (maybe) a 8-bit relocation that's the difference of two different symbols. Also your code doesn't work with NASM either if you tell it to generate OS X compatible Mach-O object files with the `-f macho64` option. This isn't a problem with gas, it's a problem with the object file format.